# Add Controller to needs with Mixin

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a mixin for my controllers that use a lot of the same functions, but I need to make sure all of the controllers have access to some basic controllers too. I do this currently by adding the to `needs`.

```
// mixins/item.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    needs: ['application']
});


// controller/items.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import ItemMixin from '../mixins/item'

export default Ember.Controller.extend(ItemMixin,{
   needs: ['index']
});
```

The issue is that many of the controllers have additional controllers that are included with `needs`. From what I've tested, the `needs` in the controllers overrides what's set in the mixin.

Is there anyway to merge the `need`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `needs` **do** merge. It is what is called a "concatenated property".

What kind of test did you do that showed it was overridden? That would severely limit your ability to write controller mixins and superclasses, and is not how it works.

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.10.0/packages/ember-application/lib/ext/controller.js#L76.

Comment: I created the above mixin and added it to a controller with index in needs and only index was present in Ember Inspector. I'm suspecting that I need to make it a ControllerMixin instead of regular mixin.

Comment: Posted the controller.

Comment: Nvm, you're right. They're merging. I just expected it to show up in the needs property, but both controllers are present in the controller property.